# Install Facebook PHP library on Bluehost

Tags: php, facebook, bluehost

My hosting provider is Bluehost, and I'm attempting to create a Facebook app for the first time, but I do not understand how to get the files necessary installed on my hosting directory.

The facebook developer "Quick Creation Guide" says the following for step 1:

```
Extract this archive into a directory on your hosting server where you can host and run PHP code:

$ curl -L http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tarball/master | tar xvz
$ mv facebook-php-sdk-* facebook-php-sdk
$ cp facebook-php-sdk/examples/example.php index.php
```

Does anyone have any experience doing this? I am new to installing PHP in general, and have only been using hosts that have had it installed already, so I am very unfamiliar with this process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do to "install" the PHP SDK is download the lone PHP file (source available [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/raw/master/src/facebook.php)), upload it to your server, and include it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: And to add, using the command line (SSH) doesn't mean that you are actually "*installing*" something. The three lines above just mean:1) download the library 2) rename the folder folder 3) rename the example file :-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I was getting incredibly frustrated. Thanks again!

Comment: As I thought, this link is now defunct. You have to use Composer, which would require CLI access, which is only on dedicated server plans on BlueHost :(

Comment: @BlakeNeal you should be able to use composer to install the library locally, vendor it, and then copy your code and vendor directory up to BlueHost. That should eliminate the need for CLI access.